# Error de actualización en segundo plano de Excel a través de Python

Tags: python, excel

Tengo el siguiente código para hacer una actualización masiva de archivos de Excel a través de python, sin embargo, aunque le pongo la línea de código para que se ejecute en segundo plano, este no lo hace.

```
import os 
import pandas as pd 
import time as tm 
import win32com.client 

def actualizar_informe(ruta): 
    excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") 
    excel.Visible = False 
    libro = excel.Workbooks.Open(ruta) 
    libro.RefreshAll() tm.sleep(45) 
    libro.Save() 
    tm.sleep(5) 
    libro.Close(False) 
    tm.sleep(5) 
    excel.Quit 

df=pd.read_excel('D:\Modelos\MODELO 360\MaestroActualizar.xlsx')
df=df.dropna(subset=['Organizado']) 

   for i in df.index: 
      actualizar_informe(str(df.Organizado[i]))
```

Comment: ¿Te da un error? ¿que significa "no lo hace": todo funciona bien pero es visible o no funciona cuando es invisible?

Comment: funciona pero lo hace visible, la idea es que sea en segundo plano

Comment: Yo pondría las 2 primeras líneas del método antes del for y la última después del for. De esta forma usas un solo excel para abrir todos los libros y hacerles el refrescar. En resumen antes del for las líneas excel.... y después del for el excel.quit.